# Gulp clean gives inconsistent results

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have the following basic Gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return del('./build/public/js');
});

gulp.task('doSomething', ['clean'], function(){
  console.log(fs.existsSync('./build/public/js'));
  return gulp.src(..... // Do some stuff here
});
```

According to this, the directory `./build/public/js` is first deleted by the `clean` task. This runs synchronously since I am using `return` in that task.

Next the first thing my `doSomething` task does is prints out whether or not the `./build/public/js` directory exists or not. This should be `false` **EVERY TIME**.

But sometimes I get `true`. I have no idea why. Here is my output when it is true:

```
[13:57:13] Using gulpfile /vhosts/website/gulpfile.js
[13:57:13] Starting 'clean'...
[13:57:13] Finished 'clean' after 30 ms
[13:57:13] Starting 'doSomething'...
true
[13:57:13] 'doSomething' errored after 196 ms
[13:57:13] Error: EEXIST, mkdir '/vhosts/website/build/public/js'
```

What is going on here? Why are my results inconsistent? `clean` finishes before `doSomething` starts, so the directory should definitely be completely deleted at that point. Why would it ever return `true`, saying the directory still exists?

Answer (score 0):

You need to help gulp understand when the task is finished:

```
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  del('./build/public/js', cb);
});
```

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps

> Note: Are your tasks running before the dependencies are complete? Make sure your dependency tasks are correctly using the async run hints: take in a callback or return a promise or event stream.

Comment: But I am returning the stream as you can clearly see in my code. It should be synchronous because of that. Right?

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Didn't notice the return. Del doesn't return a stream. Fixing the answer.